# plotting two with multiple values of Y for each X

Tags: arrays, matlab, plot, cells

```
A = [4180,4180,4200,4200,4200,4330,...]
B = [94, 180, 120, 150, 110, 160 ...]
```

I have 2 arrays.

A sorted by value and each cell contains values that could be equal.

B as shown above.

I want to plot A vs B but since I have multiple values for every element of A, the plot is very ugly.

Is there a way to keep only one cells for each value of A and at the same time take the average of the corresponding cells in B?

for example:

```
A1 = [4180,4200,4330,...]
B1 = [mean(94,180),mean(120,150,110),...]
```

Comment: How do you know that for each **A** element there is **2** or **3** elements corresponding in **B** ??

Comment: each array is a field of a structure. I have a 1x81 structure and A and B are fields in that structure. I have 81 cells in my structure and each cell has an A and a B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach -

```
[A1,~,idx] = unique(A,'stable')
B1 = accumarray(idx,B,[],@mean).'
```

Faster alternatives -

```
B1 = (accumarray(idx, B)./accumarray(idx,1)).'
```

Or -

```
B1 = (accumarray(idx, B)./histc(idx,1:max(idx))).'
```

**Sample run**

Input -

```
>> A,B
A =
        4180        4180        4200        4200        4200        4330
B =
    94   180   120   150   110   160
```

Output -

```
>> A1,B1
A1 =
        4180        4200        4330
B1 =
          137       126.67          160
```

Comment: Blah... I was JUST about to write an answer with `accumarray` lol. +1.

Comment: @rayryeng Haha, well happens I guess, specially with the easy ones ;)